# XSLT Storing Value in Variable

Tags: java, xslt, jakarta-ee

I have a project that I'm working that uses XSLT to display data from the db (db2).  I'm making some variables like.....

```
<xsl:variable name="RatePerLoadedMiles1">
    <xsl:call-template name="ratePerLoadedMiles">
        <xsl:with-param name="summaryRow" select="$SummaryRow1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="numerator" select="$OperatingExpense1"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

Now the template is stored in an existing and functioning xslt file that simply stores templates for reuse.

***My question is***...  **When I call the variable `$RatePerLoadedMiles1` am I getting a value return or the content of whats between the `<xsl:variable>` and `</xsl:variable>`?**  So if I pass it values that evaluate to 5.  Will I now have 5 stored or will I have the contents of the variable tag that will evaluate to 5 each time.  I'm less concerned with the error message it's simply provided because it was request.  My main concern is to the question above.

If it matters I'm calling the variable like....

```
<td class="rightAligned">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$RatePerLoadedMiles1" />
</td>
```

and I'm also using it do some additional calculations with....

```
<td class="rightAligned"><!-- RPLM -->
    <xsl:call-template name="formatAsPercent">
        <xsl:with-param name="numberToFormat">
            <xsl:call-template name="divideNumbers">
                <xsl:with-param name="numerator" select="$RatePerLoadedMiles1 + 
                                                         $RatePerLoadedMilesBefore + 
                                                         $RatePerLoadedMilesAfter" />
                <xsl:with-param name="denominator" select="3" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</td>
```

The output is from the browser...

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
>   Trident/4.0; EasyBits GO v1.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
>   3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; MDDR;
>   FDM) Timestamp: Tue, 9 Aug 2011 14:24:01 UTC
>
> Message: A reference to variable or parameter 'RatePerLoadedMiles'
>   cannot be resolved.  The variable or parameter may not be defined, or
>   it may not be in scope.
>
> Line: 1385 Char: 2 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://costanalysis:13000/costAnalysis/protected/javascript/xWireClientFull.jsb

Comment: Did you run the template? Please show us your output.

Comment: Where is the question mark? I cannot see the exact question.

Comment: I've updated the question with a "?" :) as well as displayed the error message I'm receiving from the browser.  The xml is generated at runtime so I can't debug without doing so at runtime (that I'm aware of).

Comment: You seem are referencing a variable in the wrong scope. What's the question?

Comment: I've put the question in bold type.  That is my main concern at the moment......I have read http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/xsltc/xsl_variable_design.html and unless I'm blind it doesn't seem to answer my question.

Comment: I'm kind of curious why this was down voted?  I've done research and modified the question to match requests from comments...  I felt it was a legit question based on my existing knowledge and research...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is that the variable RatePerLoadedMiles1 stores the value 5 (as an RTF, as @Michael Kay described). It is **not re-evaluated** when `$RatePerLoadedMiles1` is referenced.

If it is giving you the error message you posted, then you apparently forgot the `1` on the end when referencing it somewhere, because the error message says `RatePerLoadedMiles`.

Comment: I had actually changed the variable name but didn't recopy the error message (since it was the same except for the var name).  The system has some dependency on other xsl documents and I had received the same message due to a naming conflict before so I was trying a quick name change.

Answer (score 0):

The content of an `xsl:variable` is used as a sequence constructor. In the example fragment provided in the question, the variable will be populated with a set of 0 or more nodes or atomic values as returned by the `xsl:call-template` instruction itself.

Answer (score 0):

The value of your variable is (in XSLT 1.0) a "result tree fragment" which is technically a document node with children, except that there are restrictions on what you can do with it. But if you use it as a string, you will effectively get the string value of the document node, and if you use it as a number, you will get that string converted to a number.

But this is nothing to do with the error message, which is saying that you are referencing the variable from outside its scope.